# Inflating a custom control in Android

Tags: android, layout-inflater

In my activity I have a custom made control. In onCreate I inflate the activity's view as normal with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.image_viewer);
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <MyCustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/tivImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is a reduced piece of code for MyCustomTextView:

```
 public class MyCustomImageView extends ImageView
 {
  Context context;

  public MyCustomImageView(Context context)
  {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
  }

  public MyCustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
  }
 }
```

The exception that gets generated reads:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class MyCustomImageView
```

Comment: Do you generate constructors like the superclass?

Comment: The XML you posted is not the one you're using, since you're getting an error on inflating `MyCustomImageView`, and your XML contains `MyCustomTextView` instead. Please edit in a correction.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the code above. I changed the name while pasting it into SO. It really is MyCustomImageView. Thanks for pointing that out but I still have the problem.

Comment: @minipif I added the constructors above. Yes they are in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add the package name:

```
 <com.my.package.MyCustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/tivImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: I thought Android attempts to use your app's default package name when it can't figure out where something originates from. Apparently that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create constructors calling the superclass constructors, because they will be called by the inflater:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

And you have to put the full package name in your XML:

```
<com.mypackagename.MyView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```